# How to change a variable in a treemap while printing?

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

I'm working on my java project. [pic of a map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rDrc.png)

The value of the map is an object with double and int variables.
I have to print out this map but all 0's have to be replaced with "unknown". How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I have tried to do something with toString method but it would need a lot of 'if' conditions. I don't have and idea how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
map.entrySet().stream().forEach((k, v) -> {
    System.out.println(v.toString().replaceAll("0+\.0+", "unknown");
}));
```

Comment: Im getting error message "illegal escape character".